# jQuery/JS: How can I loop over two arrays while an if else toggles a class?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm looping over two arrays, `selectedLabelsTemp` which looks like `[1,8]` and the `rosterLabelList`...$(this).data looks like `[1,8,2,12]` I'm trying to make it so that when it goes into the if else statement, $(this) will get the class check-active, and then no more class changes. However, since I'm looping over selectLabelsTemp, the first time I hit 1, it will add the class check-active, but since this 1 is still present, and the next time each starts looping, it will see that the class check-active is present on the $(this).data('id') == 1 so then it goes into the else statement and removes the class. I would like to make it so that when I trigger this, the $(this) with 1 and 8 will have the class check-active.. and the second time I click it will remove the check-active class from 1 and 8 ( or basically whatever is inside the selectedLabelsTemp array).
My code is like this.. Thanks in advance for the help!

I think I could make another variable that is a copy of selectedLabelsTemp and that whatever is in that array index after it gets matched with the $(this).data('id)... but I'm not sure if that's a good idea?

```
//a jquery trigger wraps this
rosterLabelList.find(".roster-label-link").each(function( index ){
                for(var i = 0, len = selectedLabelsTemp.length; i<len; i++){
                    console.log(selectedLabelsTemp[i]);
                    if($(this).data('id') == selectedLabelsTemp[i]){

                        $(this).addClass('check-active');
                    }
                    else{
                        if($(this).hasClass('check-active')){
                            $(this).removeClass('check-active');
                        }

                    }
                }
```

EDIT: I'm having issues using the first answer below. It works the first time with selectedLabels, but it does not work with my selectedLabelsFull array. By not working, I mean it doesn't add the check-active-full class. `console.log(selectedLabels)` gives back `1, 3, 8, 14, 15` and `console.log(selectedLabelsFull)` gives back `1, 8`
All of the console.logs inside the filter function seems to give back `false`.. What's going on here?
I've also noticed that if I change selectedLabelsTemp in the filter function with [2,4] and the $(this).data('id') contains 2 and 4, the check-active-full class will be added... This makes me think that there is something wrong with `selectedLabelsFull`? If I `typeof` for selectedLabels and selectedLabelsFull... they're both objects, and they're both defined right next to each other as arrays.

```
            rosterLabelList
            .find(".roster-label-link")
            .removeClass("check-active")
            .filter(function () {
                console.log("CHECKACTIVE");
                console.log( $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), selectedLabels) > -1);
                return $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), selectedLabels ) > -1; 
            })
            .addClass("check-active");

            rosterLabelList
            .find(".roster-label-link")
            .removeClass("check-active-full")
            .filter(function () {
                console.log("checkactivefull");
                console.log( $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), selectedLabelsFull ) > -1);
                return $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), selectedLabelsFull ) > -1; 
            })
            .addClass("check-active-full");
```

Comment: You have a `data-id="..."` attribute on your labels, instad of a simple  `id="..."` attribute? Why?

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not really sure. The code base was passed on to me and there are data-id's everywhere, so I have to work with it.

Comment: Well, if it is by intention, then that's the way it is. I just wanted to cross-check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems overly compicated. How about this:

```
rosterLabelList
.find(".roster-label-link")
.removeClass("check-active")
.filter(function () {
    return $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), selectedLabelsTemp ) > -1; 
})
.addClass("check-active");
```

or, a bit shorter (but also a bit less obvious when reading it):

```
rosterLabelList
.find(".roster-label-link")
.each(function () {
    var isActive = $.inArray( $(this).data('id'), selectedLabelsTemp ) > -1
    $.toggleClass("check-active", isActive); 
});
```

Comment: The first one works better for me because I've got to add another class for situations in which the count of a value that appears in SelectedLabelsTemp matches the count of the values of that number in another array.

Comment: I'm having some issues using your code with a different array.. Can you please look at my edited post? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `console.log()`, set a break point and inspect the *actual* data in the debugger.

Comment: hmm.. I haven't used that before... let me try and figure this thing out.

Comment: Ah! I figured it out... The values of `selectedLabelsAll` were non integers so I just used `parseInt()`... Oh man this took me way too long to fix. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: But you've learned quite a few of important lessons, so that time hasn't been wasted. :) (Final hint, don't forget the radix parameter of `parseInt()`, i.e. `parseInt(str, 10);`)

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop of your code is needless, and has some logic problem.

Suggesting there are 2 array : A[1,2], B[2,1]. If you compare `A.1` with `B.2`, you would trigger `removeClass` in your case, but both we know that we are just checking if elements of A is in array B. You must loop over all the elements of B, but not just compare the first element and return true or false.

Javascript doesn't offer a `in_array` liked method, where jquery does. Check this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/

Or, you can fix it by using traditional javascript without jquery:

```
function inArray(ary, find) {
    var len = ary.length;
    var ret = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arguments[1] == ary[i]) {
            ret = true;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```